# How to know if it is possible to rearrange columns of a matrix to avoid nulls on the diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a square matrix with binary entries, 1 - 0.

Is there a mathematical way/trick/algorithm to know if it is possible to rearrange the columns in order to have all the elements on the main diagonal non null?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "rearrange the columns"?

Comment: That I don't care if the 10th column becomes the first. Let's say that I have _n_ vectors of length _n_, and I want to put them in a matrix _n_ x _n_ which has the main diagonal with no nulls.

Comment: You want this : $I_{N*N}$ ?

Comment: No, I don't care about the other elements. What I want is a matrix with no nulls on its main diagonal.

Comment: It is really simple and can be done in programming, like matlab codes

Comment: Any hint on the algorithm? That's what I want to do, but I'm looking for a fast algorithm, faster than trying every permutation.

Comment: yep, I am working on it, I will post the code here in the answer!

Comment: @foebu the last question: "IF you must be loyal to the 1 positions (other elemnts I mean)?"

Comment: I don't care about any position, I can put the columns however I want. If I got your question.

Comment: shouldn't the matrix at least be regular?

Comment: and so why dont try first $I_{N*N}$ and then add th $1s$

Comment: The [Hall marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) might help here.

Comment: @Cardinal, my vectors are given, I can't change them. I'll have a look at the Hall marriage theorem, though.

Comment: I think you might be able to exploit the stable marriage algorithm for this application, maybe worth looking into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem), it is sufficient to check that for any subset $S$ of size $k$ of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, we have at least $k$ columns that have a $1$ in the "$s$th" position for some $s \in S$.

Checking this condition directly (as opposed to checking all permutations) takes us down from a $O(n \cdot n!)$ method to a $O(n^2\cdot 2^n)$ method.

I don't believe this is the most efficient approach.  You should try looking for "matching algorithms" in literature.  Perhaps [this will prove useful](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1983-088-01/S0002-9939-1983-0691291-0/S0002-9939-1983-0691291-0.pdf).

Comment: Let me know if you're interested in some kind of code for the basic Hall's theorem method.

Comment: Thank you very much, some code might be useful. At max I have 11 vectors and my matrix would be 11x11. I'm reducing anyway the size of the matrix given to some other rules, so my matrix will be often a 8x8 or 7x7. Anyway the problem I'm trying to solve is exactly that one.

Comment: May any sorting algorithm be quicker?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know a whole lot about this problem, so maybe there are quicker algorithms around.

Comment: By the way, a followup question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368617/is-the-proposed-a-different-version-of-the-stable-marriage-problem-and-a-valid-g)

Answer (score 0):

the trick is to reduce the size of the problem. so if you can rearrange the rows and columns such that you get a  1 in diag $1$, and zeros on the rest of the first row and column, then you can forget the first row and column, and continue with the submatrix of size $(N-1)\times(N-1)$. if you can't get a $1$ alone in diag $1$, then I propose to minimize the number of wasted $1$ in the rest of column and row $1$. and in the case you wasted some $1$'s, I don't know if it is useful to backtrack if no solution is founded at the end, that's the interesting question. if not, you would get a $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ algorithm ?

Comment: Though it is worth noting that the question only allows re-ordering of columns, not rows and columns.