# Is the proposed a different version of the stable marriage problem and a valid Gale-Shapley solution?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

my problem is the following.

I've two sets A and B with the same numbe of elements.
The elements in A can match only with some elements of B. The elements of B have no preferences. Elements have no preferences too, but they can't be matched to any element of B.

I try to represent my sets and possible matches in a matrix, where the elements of A are the columns, the element of B are the rows.

```
  1 2 3 4 5
A 1 1 0 0 0
B 1 1 1 0 0
C 0 0 1 1 1
D 0 0 1 1 1
E 1 1 0 0 0
```

I try to give preferencies counting how many matchable elements are on a row or on a column, and give priority to the "least matchable" (the rarest) rows/columns.
In this case:

```
Set A
1 3
2 3
3 3
4 2
5 2

Set B
A 2
B 3
C 3
D 3
E 2
```

So, I build a preferences table:

```
A B C D E
1 1 4 4 1
2 2 5 5 2
  3 3 3
```

Same thing for the set A:

```
1 2 3 4 5
A A B C C
E E C D D
B B D
```

I use the algorithm described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtTV6rIxhdo).

First round: all elements of set B choose their top preference of set A:

```
A B C D E
1 1 4 4 1
```

Set A accepts all "first seeded" proposals and rejects the others, so at the end of the round these are the matches accepted:

```
1 2 3 4 5
A   B C
```

Second round, B and C propose respectively to 3 and 4. These matches are accepted, everyone is happy.

```
1 2 3 4 5
A E B C D
```

Where my problem lies? Can I demonstrate that such an algorithm always works? I won't always have problems with a solution, and I'm happy with that, but I want that my algorithm fails when there is no solution and works when there is a solution.

Is it correct to threat the preferences the way I did, choosing those priorities, even though they are not real priorities?

Again: I just want all matches fulfilled, I don't properly care about "stability", so I don't even know if this is a stable marriage problem.
What I want is to have all elements of Set B matched to one and only one element of set A, if this is possible.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The only difference from Gale-Shapley is how you choose the priority matrix. The priority is basically which solutions to keep first. You could argue that G-S is correct, and since your priority matrix is just one subcase of the domain , then your G-S is also correct. In this case correct is meant as "G-S" correct,i.e. terminates, produces stable couples ( implying bijectivity).

Comment: I wonder if there might be any solution which would imply a step back for an element of set A.